# Can I use a dictionary as my 'data' object for rectangles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to make four rectangles with set widths and heights.

```
var rects = {
  key1:  { x: base_x, y: base_y, fullname: "Seed", cnt: 3500, row: 1 },
  key2:  { x: 2*base_x, y: base_y, fullname: "Series A", cnt: 4700, row: 1 },
  key3:  { x: 3*base_x, y: base_y, fullname: "Series B", cnt: 2300, row: 1},
  key4:  { x: 4*base_x, y: base_y, fullname: "Series C", cnt: 1750, row: 1}}
```

I know that I can turn these into rectangles if I replace `{}` with `[]` to turn it into an array and if I get rid of the keys since arrays can't have keys and then I can use this.

```
var rectangles = svg.selectAll(".rect")
    .data(rects)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
```

I'd like to work with the `rects` object later on in a function that requires keys.

I suppose I can make an array based off of rects with something like this

```
var rects_array = []
for (i = 0; i < d3.keys(rects).length; i++){
    rects_array.push(rects[d3.keys(rects)[i]])
}
```

I was just curious if I could pass `rects` in directly instead of making an array from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **no**, you can't.

D3 `data()` method accepts only 3 things:

- an array;
- a function;
- nothing.

Therefore, you cannot use an object here.

Regarding your last snippet, the easiest way to create an array based on the `rects` object is using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
var rects = {
  key1: {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar",
    fullname: "Seed",
    cnt: 3500,
    row: 1
  },
  key2: {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar",
    fullname: "Series A",
    cnt: 4700,
    row: 1
  },
  key3: {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar",
    fullname: "Series B",
    cnt: 2300,
    row: 1
  },
  key4: {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar",
    fullname: "Series C",
    cnt: 1750,
    row: 1
  }
};

console.log(Object.values(rects))
```

Alternatively, if you want a D3 method, you can use [`d3.values`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/v1.0.7/README.md#values), which internally uses a `for...in` loop:

```js
var rects = {
  key1: {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar",
    fullname: "Seed",
    cnt: 3500,
    row: 1
  },
  key2: {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar",
    fullname: "Series A",
    cnt: 4700,
    row: 1
  },
  key3: {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar",
    fullname: "Series B",
    cnt: 2300,
    row: 1
  },
  key4: {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar",
    fullname: "Series C",
    cnt: 1750,
    row: 1
  }
};

console.log(d3.values(rects))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Then pass that array to `selection.data()`, and use your `rects` object somewhere else, according to your needs.